# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Biology Stack Exchange](http://biology.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://biology.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why are transmembrane proteins difficult to crystallise?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13523/why-are-transmembrane-proteins-difficult-to-crystallise)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are the differences between HPRD and BIOGRID databases?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13726/what-are-the-differences-between-hprd-and-biogrid-databases)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Hardy Weinberg Equilibrium problem](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/hardy-weinberg-equilibrium-problem)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Calculation of saturation of carbon in surface waters](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13713/calculation-of-saturation-of-carbon-in-surface-waters)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What does orbital mean in orbital frontal cortex?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/what-does-orbital-mean-in-orbital-frontal-cortex)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [pfu Turbo DNA polymerase AD](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/pfu-turbo-dna-polymerase-ad)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How easy is it to carry out de novo sequence assembly?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13819/how-easy-is-it-to-carry-out-de-novo-sequence-assembly)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Double mutant analysis with null mutants](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13883/double-mutant-analysis-with-null-mutants)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Cats, Dogs and Bears - how are they related?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/cats-dogs-and-bears-how-are-they-related)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How predictably will RNA polymerase not transcribe repetitive sequences?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13618/how-predictably-will-rna-polymerase-not-translate-repetitive-sequences)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Answer (score 2):

In general there seem to be two problems I see

1) search engine optimization. There were several good questions with excellent answers that I had to list as 'needs improvement' solely because I had difficulty finding them unless I basically put the exact question into google. I am no expert on SEO, so for those in the know, it must be possible to improve the stature of this site so that more tangential search queries still get directed toward here. How?

2) Several poorly researched questions. At first I was dismayed, but I read [this](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/should-let-me-google-it-for-you-questions-be-tolerated?rq=1) meta-Biology SE post and I agree with the sentiment of Rory M. I think we should go so far as to make his recommendations part of the official guide to Biology SE: downvote poorly researched questions, and take those poorly researched questions as an opportunity to write a thoughtful, in-depth, and thoroughly researched answer that will add value to anyone else who could just google it (then upvote those good answers!).

Comment: Number two advocates for the reversal badge. Maybe there is a better approach; I always thought that was a weird badge. Couldn't we just edit the question?