# How do you flag questions which show no effort whatsoever?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I have been on bio stackexchange for little over a year now, and have encountered many great questions, but also many badly researched and trivial queries.

Usually when I see something that goes against the guidelines, I flag it to draw  attention to other either the community or the moderators, but to flag a "no-research-no-effort-question" for moderator attention seems pure overkill to me. Should one then just flag such a question as "homework"?

Edit: the question might be a dupe for [this question](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/should-let-me-google-it-for-you-questions-be-tolerated?rq=1) but not entirely sure

Comment: Vote for closure.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I know that, but what reason do I then give? I cannot just select vote to close - I have to specify the reason.

Comment: @WYSIWYG - I found my answer here: http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/updating-statement-on-closed-reason-for-no-work-shown?rq=1 I hence VTC my question

Comment: Also see http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/3493/3340